# WCF service listens only localhost (127.0.0.1)

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, server, ip

I have WCF service which works as windows service. Service works fine, tested with 100+ clients. But one machine works only on localhost. Service is hosted on windows server 2012 r2. Adding image of 'netstat'. On similar working server, service is listening on '0.0.0.0:88'.

[image]

Tried various endpoints '0.0.0.0:88/MyService.svc', '198.x.x.x:88/MyService.svc', 'HostName:88/MyService.svc' all work localy only.

Service config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="connectionString" value="xxxxx"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>    
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="BehaviourService">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="FvsBasicHttp" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00" openTimeout="00:20:00" closeTimeout="00:20:00"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxDepth="32" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="FvsWebServiceWcf.FvsService" behaviorConfiguration="BehaviourService" >
        <endpoint name="FvsService" address ="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="FvsBasicHttp" contract="FvsWebServiceWcf.IFvsService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://195.x.x.x:88/MyService.asmx"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: then show the config of your wcf service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible guess: Someone messed the machine up by setting HTTP.SYS to only listen on the localhost interface. You could check this by running the command:

`netsh.exe http show iplisten`

If it does return 127.0.0.1 as expected, you probably need to remove the entry with (`netsh.exe http delete iplisten ipaddress=127.0.0.1`). Not sure if you'd need to add 0.0.0.0 again just to get it to work again.

Comment: tomasr thanks alot, saved my day. Commands: "netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=0.0.0.0" and "netsh http delete iplisten ipaddress=127.0.0.1"